# Skip reading certain parts in text file python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, function, text-files

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Solid ASCII
  facet normal -6.275966e-02 3.134884e-02 -9.975362e-01
    outer loop
      vertex   -4.624000e-01 5.000000e-01 -2.023656e-01
      vertex   -4.624742e-01 4.811628e-01 -2.029529e-01
      vertex   -5.000000e-01 5.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
    endloop
  endface
```

[image]

I attached a photo to explain the indentation that the text have in the lines. I only want to read the numbers and fill in a specific way that is working but the way that I manage is:

```
with open (r'CamaSTL.txt','r+') as infile,\
 open (r'CamaSTL2.txt','w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
    line = infile.read()
    line = line.replace("facet normal", "")
    line = line.replace("outer loop", "")
    line = line.replace("vertex","")
    line = line.replace("endloop","")
    line = line.replace("endfacet","")
    line = line.replace("endsolid","")
outfile.write(line)

f = open('CamaSTL2.txt','r')
obj1_normal = []
obj1_v1 = []
obj1_v2 = []
obj1_v3 = []
array = []
n = []

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if(line):
        for x in line.split():
            array.append(float(x))

i=0

while i < (len(array)):
    n=[array[i],array[i+1],array[i+2]]
    obj1_normal.append(n)
    v1 =[array[i+3], array[i+4], array[i+5]]
    obj1_v1.append(v1)
    v2 =[array[i+6],array[i+7],array[i+8]]
    obj1_v2.append(v2)
    v3 =[array[i+9],array[i+10],array[i+11]]
    obj1_v3.append (v3)
    i +=12

for row in obj1_normal:
    print (row)
```

Removing the words, generating a new file, read the new generate file and place the numbers in the way I want. Is there a way to not generate a new file, "skip" the reading of those words, and only read and attached the numbers? Because I'm going to make arithmetic operations with arrays that I create and then I will want to save in the same way (with the words at the beginning of the strings because I will need)

Comment: you could format text with data to show indentations - you don't have to add image for this.

Comment: why to write data to file only to read it again? You should create new list with all lines. And you can add only lines which are not empty after replacing. And when you use `for line in infile` then you don't have to use `infile.read()` because you already have line in variable `line`

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach may be useful for you:

```py
import re

fp_number_regex = re.compile(r"[-+][0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+")


def filter_floats(lines):
    for line in lines:
        r = re.findall(fp_number_regex, line)
        if r:
            yield r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(r'CamaSTL.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for floats_in_line in filter_floats(infile):
            print(floats_in_line)
```

**Output:**

```py
['-6.275966e-02', '-9.975362e-01']
['-4.624000e-01', '-2.023656e-01']
['-4.624742e-01', '-2.029529e-01']
['-5.000000e-01', '-2.000000e-01']
```

I am using a regex (that I found [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s10.html)) to match floating point numbers in a string. The `filter_floats` function now per line yields a list of the floating points found in this line. If there are none, the line is just skipped.